# MikTeX: Failing to compile in sublime text 3

Tags: miktex, sublime-text

When I compile in Sublime Text 3, a PDF does not appear, instead I get the following message:

```
shell_cmd or cmd is required
[cmd: None]
```

I have already installed Latextools, and i've added SumatraPDF to my path

Comment: What exactly is latextools? You need a latex distribution in order to compile your document. That is what sublime is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

[LaTeXTools is a plugin for sublime](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools). I assume you have a LaTeX-distribution ([MikTeX](https://miktex.org/) on Windows). Nothing will work if you haven't.

However, the error message looks like your build system is not correctly configured.

Check which build system you use (Tools -> Build System). For me, `automatic` works.
If it doesn't for you, create a new Build System (Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...). A new document shows up with the following content:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "make"
}
```

replace `make` with the command you want to run. I'd suggest to chose a very simple one like `pdflatex` (I don't know how to compile latex from command line on windows, but I think you can figure out, it shouldn't be that hard).
Save the document as `<name>.sublime-build` (don't change the default path or ending, but you can edit the filename), then activate it (again Tools -> Build System -> `<name>`).

If building works, you can enhance the command step by step (e.g. enable synctex).